# Serializable vs Externalizable

Tags: java, сериализация

В чем разница между этими видами сериализации?
Для своей реализации сериализации в `Serialilzable` я могу определить методы (`private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream in)` и  `private void readObject(ObjectInputStream out)`).
Так зачем же тогда `Externalizable`?

Comment: `writeObject` - приватный метод, отвечающий за сохранение состояния класса, в котором он определен. При сериализации объекта, сериализатор пройдет по всей иерархии от родителей к потомкам, и вызовет `writeObject` для каждого класса, если он есть. `writeExternal` - виртуальный метод, последний класс в иерархии, который его переопределяет, отвечает за сохранение всех классов (как предков, так и потомков).  Но это не точно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сериализация использует рефлексию для автоматического маршалинга объекта в поток байт и из потока байтов. Это позволяет просто пометить класс интерфейсом `Serializable` и больше не совершать дополнительных телодвижений. Но рефлексия, как известно - чертовски медленная штука. При "экстернализации" рефлексия не используется. С одной стороны это ускоряет процесс маршалинга\демаршалинга, а с другой **требует** от программиста реализовать его вручную.

Ещё один фактор, который стоит учитывать - при десериализации не вызывается конструктор, а при "деэкстернализации" вызывается. В некоторых случаях более удобно первое, в некоторых второе.

И отвечая на ваш комментарий к ответу Anver Bogatov, переопределение методов `writeObject` и `readObject` отчасти стирает разницу между `Serializable` и `Externalizable`.

Comment: То есть при реализации методов в обоих случаях, выигрывает Externalizable из за того что не нужно рефлексию вызывать для проверки присутствия этих методов в Serializable

Comment: Я сам замеры не проводил, но много где видел утверждение, что при любых раскладах `Externalizable` хоть чуть-чуть но быстрее.

Answer (score 0):

Serializable - это интерфейс-маркер (не имеет методов) и указывает на то, что его имплементор поддерживает сериализацию / десериализацию дефолтными механизмами (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)

Externalizable - определяет свой набор методов, которые имплементор должен реализовать. Этот интерфейс нужно использовать в тех случаях, когда необходимо самостоятельно реализовать процессы сериализации / десериализации (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html)

Comment: private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream in)
private void readObject(ObjectInputStream out)
Это два метода которые можно добавить в Serializable в случаях "когда необходимо самостоятельно реализовать процессы сериализации / десериализации"